# Regarding High Availability for MSSQL Server

Tags: database, high-availability, database-administration, sql-server-2012, migration

Already used in MySQL : Real Time Replication (synchronization) between primary and secondary server is done using master and slave commands. So What is the equivalent feature for MsSQL. Which Replication method should be used for real time synchronization? And is it supported in standard edition or do I need to purchase MsSQL enterprise edition?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/81208/mysql-high-availability?rq=1

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the MySQL HA question.  This isn't asking how to do MySQL HA, it's asking what the equivalent is in MSSQL.

Comment: Agreed squillman.

Answer (score 3):

What version of MSSQL are you looking at this for?

[SQL 2012 HA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190202.aspx) options include AlwaysOn solutions which leverages Microsoft's failover clustering but adds functionality on top of it. Or you can setup log shipping to create a standby database. Technically, I think you can still do database mirroring in MSSQL 2012 but that is going to be deprecated in some future release of MS SQL

[MS SQL 2008 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff658546%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and going back to at least SQL 2005, you can also setup Log Shipping or database mirroring along with setting up a straight Windows Failover Cluster of the database servers.

Regarding licensing, I could give you some general advice, but I would advise you to talk to a licensing VAR specialist to get what you need. In general, anything using failover clustering features (AlwaysOn, Windows Failover Cluster) will require a OS enterprise license except for Windows 2012 - If you are running on WIndows 2012, you can use the Windows 2012 Standard license level. LogShipping and mirroring should not have any base Windows OS license restrictions. Note: I'm talking about Windows version licensing at this point, not SQL version licensing. SQL license level LogShipping and DB Mirroring should be available at the SQL Standard license level. AlwaysOn might require the enterprise (can't remember off the top of my head).

Again - make sure you talk to someone else on the licensing piece to make sure you purchase what you require.

Comment: The problem with AO groups is that IIRC they are enterprise, while mirroring is Standard ;)

Comment: Did a quick check - AlawysOn Availability Groups are SQL Enterprise only. You can do a AlwaysOn Failover Instance with SQL Standard (but this is really just a regular Windows Cluster requiring shared storage, etc).